# Inserir múltiplos registros type file no Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, upload

Estou fazendo um formulário, onde tem uma parte de cadastro de imagens para uma galeria de fotos.

Nesse campo eu uso um script com um botão de adicionar campo para que possa ser inserido um novo campo para cada foto

```html
<label>Galeria de Foto</label>
<BR><BR>
<button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Adicionar + Foto</button>
<br>
<div id="listas">
    <div><input name="fotos[]" type="file" class="form-control" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="width: 70%;"></div>
</div>
```

Esse é o script que adiciona o novo campo:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var campos_max          = 10;   //max de 10 campos
    var x = 1; // campos iniciais
    $('#add_field').click (function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();     //prevenir novos clicks
            if (x < campos_max) {
                    $('#listas').append('<div>\
                    <input name="fotos[]" type="file" class="form-control" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="width: 70%;">\
                            <a href="#" class="remover_campo">Remover</a>\
                            </div>');
                    x++;
            }
    });

    // Remover o div anterior
    $('#listas').on("click",".remover_campo",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
    });
});
</script>
```

Até ai tudo bem. Ele cria um novo campo file, com nome **fotos[]**. 
E faz o upload para a pasta que eu defini, sem erro algum.

O problema esta no momento de salvar o nome de cada imagem no banco de dados.

Após enviar o formulário por post ele executa o seguinte:

```
<?
//include_once("config.php");
$nome_embarcacao = $_POST[nome];
$tipo = $_POST[tipo];
$arquivo = $_POST[arquivo];
$capacidade = $_POST[capacidade];
$tamanho = $_POST[tamanho];
$motorizacao = $_POST[motorizacao];
$equipamentos = $_POST[equipamentos];
$periodo_passeio = $_POST[periodo_passeio];
$area_navegacao = $_POST[area_navegacao];
$descricao = $_POST[descricao];


$sql = "INSERT INTO `embarcacao` (`id`, `nome`, `tipo`, `arquivo`, `capacidade`, `tamanho`, `motorizacao`, `equipamentos`, `periodo_passeio`, `area_navegacao`, `descricao`) VALUES (NULL, '$nome_embarcacao', '$tipo', '$arquivo', '$capacidade', '$tamanho', '$motorizacao', '$equipamentos', '$periodo_passeio', '$area_navegacao', '$descricao');";
$sql = mysql_query($sql);

$id_recuperado = mysql_insert_id();

// inicia criação de pasta
$pasta = @mkdir("../assets/images/embarcacoes/$id_recuperado");

// fim da criação da pasta
$uploaddir="../assets/images/embarcacoes/$id_recuperado/";

if($arquivo != "none") {// verifica campo foto 1
if (copy($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_FILES['arquivo']['name'])) {
$varfoto01 = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
$var1 = mysql_query("update embarcacao set arquivo='$varfoto01' where 
id='$id_recuperado'");
}}


// Pasta de destino das fotos 
$Destino = "../assets/images/embarcacoes/$id_recuperado/"; 
// Obtém dados do upload 
$Fotos = $_FILES["fotos"]; 
// Contagem de fotos enviadas 
$Conta = 0; 

// Itera sobre as enviadas e processa as validações e upload 
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($Fotos); $i++) 
{ 
 // Passa valores da iteração atual 
 $Nome = $Fotos["name"][$i]; 
 $Tamanho = $Fotos["size"][$i]; 
 $Tipo = $Fotos["type"][$i]; 
 $Tmpname = $Fotos["tmp_name"][$i]; 

 // Verifica se tem arquivo enviado 
if($Tamanho > 0 && strlen($Nome) > 1) 
{ 
 // Verifica se é uma imagem 
 if(preg_match("/^image\/(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$/", $Tipo)) 
 { 
 // Caminho completo de destino da foto 
 $Caminho = $Destino . $Nome; 

 // Tudo OK! Move o upload! 
 if(move_uploaded_file($Tmpname, $Caminho)) 
 { 

 $sql_fotos = "INSERT INTO `embarcacao_fotos` (`id`, `id_embarcacao`, `arquivo`) VALUES";

foreach($_POST['fotos'] AS $indice => $valor) {

  $sql_fotos .= " (NULL, '{$id_recuperado}', '{$valor}'),";
}

echo "Foto #" . ($i+1) . " enviada.<br/>"; 

// Faz contagem de enviada com sucesso 
$Conta++; 
} 
else // Erro no envio 
{ 
 // $i+1 porque $i começa em zero 
 echo "Não foi possível enviar a foto #" . ($i+1) . "<br/>"; 
} 
} 
} 
} 

if($Conta) // Imagens foram enviadas, ok! 
{ 
echo "<br/>Foi(am) enviada(s) " . $Conta . " foto(s).";
} 

else // Nenhuma imagem enviada, faz alguma ação 
{ 
echo "Você não enviou fotos!"; 
}
?>
```

Lá em **foreach($_POST['fotos']**, ele não insere no banco de dados o nome de cada arquivo.

Gostaria de saber se alguém consegue me ajudar. Com essa função de salvar os nomes dos arquivos do campo `fotos[]` no banco de dados. Só preciso disso. Salvar seus nomes, pois o *upload* na pasta criada ele já esta fazendo normal.

Desculpa se meu post for duplicado e desculpa se não consegui explicar direito. Sou novo em criar artigo para solicitar ajuda. Sempre consigo achar alguem com o mesmo problema e resolver pela pergunta dele. Mas esse aqui já procurei e não achei alguem com o mesmo problema.

Abraço a todos

Comment: Você não pode terminar o comando SQL com vírgula. E cuidado que você está usando a biblioteca `mysql_`, que foi descontinuada. Veja [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/74)

Comment: Olá amigo.
Obrigado por responder. Onde esta a virgula que mencionou?
Abraço

Comment: Diga-me o que exatamente você quer salvar no banco com a variável `$valor`

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo então Leo, eu quero salvar no banco de dados o nome de cada arquivo. A tabela tem essa estrutura que esta ai no SQL_fotos. O upload dos arquivos já estão sendo feitos normal. Mas o nome não salva. Na verdade não salva nenhum registro.

Comment: Se alguma resposta resolveu seu problema marque-a como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use o `foreach` para gerar a string

   ```
   foreach($_POST['fotos'] AS $indice => $valor) {
     $values .= " (NULL, '{$id_recuperado}', '{$valor}'),";
   }
   ```
2. Retire a ultima virgula da string

   ```
   $values=substr($values, 0, -1);
   ```
3. Use a string como value da declaração INSERT

   ```
    $sql_fotos = "INSERT INTO `embarcacao_fotos` (`id`, `id_embarcacao`, `arquivo`) VALUES $values";
   ```

> Analisando seu código após tê-lo identado de forma mais legível, verifiquei que a lógica está errada. O `foreach` está dentro de um loop `for` e  dessa forma a variável `$values` está sendo criada de forma errada.  Portanto refiz o código de modo que o upload e insert na tabela `embarcacao_fotos` sejam executados corretamente e com a extensão  [**mysqli_***](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)

```
<?php

//coloquei esse if mas você faça do modo que deva ser do seu interesse, eé da ultima chave de fechamento
if (isset($_POST['tipo'])) {

/**não devemos usar "mysql" pelo seu desenvolvimento ter sido descontinuado; a extensão se tornou obsoleta e essas funções não irão funcionar em futuras versões do PHP*/
//include_once("config.php");

//use mysqli ou PDO
$conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "Usuario", "Senha", "nome_DB");

$nome_embarcacao = $_POST['nome'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$arquivo = $_POST['arquivo'];
$capacidade = $_POST['capacidade'];
$tamanho = $_POST['tamanho'];
$motorizacao = $_POST['motorizacao'];
$equipamentos = $_POST['equipamentos'];
$periodo_passeio = $_POST['periodo_passeio'];
$area_navegacao = $_POST['area_navegacao'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];

//com mysqli
$sql = "INSERT INTO `embarcacao` (`id`, `nome`, `tipo`, `arquivo`, `capacidade`, `tamanho`, `motorizacao`, `equipamentos`, `periodo_passeio`, `area_navegacao`, `descricao`) VALUES (NULL, '$nome_embarcacao', '$tipo', '$arquivo', '$capacidade', '$tamanho', '$motorizacao', '$equipamentos', '$periodo_passeio', '$area_navegacao', '$descricao');";
$executa = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$id_recuperado = $conn->insert_id;

// inicia criação de pasta

mkdir("../assets/images/embarcacoes/$id_recuperado/", 0777, true);

// fim da criação da pasta
$uploaddir="../assets/images/embarcacoes/$id_recuperado/";

if($arquivo != "none") {// verifica campo foto 1
if (copy($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_FILES['arquivo']['name'])) {
$varfoto01 = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

//com mysqli
$conn->query("UPDATE embarcacao set arquivo='$varfoto01' where 
id='$id_recuperado'"); 
}}

/************************************************************************************/
/********  daqui pra baixo faz upload e insert na tabela embarcacao_fotos ***********/
/************************************************************************************/

$j = 0;

// Pasta de destino das fotos
$caminhoDestino = "../assets/images/embarcacoes/$id_recuperado/";

$Fotos=$_FILES['fotos'];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($Fotos['name']); $i++) {
        //nome e extensão do arquivo
        $nome = ($Fotos['name'][$i]);

        if($nome!=""){
            //constroi os values da declaração INSERT para a tabela embarcacao_fotos
            $values .= " (NULL, '{$id_recuperado}', '{$nome}'),";

             $extensoesValidas = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");
             //basename() retorna apenas a parte que corresponde ao nome do arquivo.
             $ext = explode('.', basename($Fotos['name'][$i]));

             //end() avança o ponteiro interno de array até o seu último elemento, e retorna-o.
             $extensaoArquivo = end($ext);

             // Caminho completo de destino da foto
             $caminhoCompleto = $caminhoDestino.$nome;

             $j = $j + 1;
                if (($Fotos["size"][$i]>0) && in_array($extensaoArquivo, $extensoesValidas)) {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($Fotos['tmp_name'][$i], $caminhoCompleto)) {
                     echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Imagem carregada com êxito!.</span><br/><img src="'.$caminhoCompleto.'" width="50px" height="50px" /><br/><br/>';
                    } else {
                     echo $j. ').<span id="error">Por favor, tente novamente!.</span><br/><br/>';
                    }
                } else {
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Tamanho ou tipo de arquivo inválido***</span><br/><br/>';
                }
        }
    }

    //retira a ultima virgula
    $values=substr($values, 0, -1);

    //declaração insert 
    $sql_fotos = "INSERT INTO `embarcacao_fotos` (`id`, `id_embarcacao`, `arquivo`) VALUES $values";
    //executa a query
    $executa = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_fotos);

    mysqli_close($conn); 


}
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var campos_max          = 10;   //max de 10 campos
    var x = 1; // campos iniciais
    $('#add_field').click (function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();     //prevenir novos clicks
            if (x < campos_max) {
                    $('#listas').append('<div>\
                    <input name="fotos[]" type="file" class="form-control" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="width: 70%;">\
                            <a href="#" class="remover_campo">Remover</a>\
                            </div>');
                    x++;
            }
    });

    // Remover o div anterior
    $('#listas').on("click",".remover_campo",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
    });
});
</script>


<form class="form-horizontal m-t-40" autocomplete="off" action="?pg=enviar_embarcacao" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
<label>Tipo Embarcação</label>
<select name="tipo" class="custom-select col-12" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
  <option selected>Selecione o tipo...</option>
  <option value="1">Alugar</option>
  <option value="2">Vender</option>
</select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
<label>Nome</label>
<div class="controls">
  <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="Nome obrigatorio!">
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
<label>Imagem destaque</label>
<div class="controls">
  <input name="arquivo" type="file" class="form-control" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp" required data-validation-required-message="Essa imagem é obrigatória!">
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Capacidade</label>
    <input name="capacidade" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-5">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Tamanho</label>
    <input name="tamanho" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-5">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Periodo Passeio</label>
    <input name="periodo_passeio" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-5">
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Area de Navegação</label>
    <input name="area_navegacao" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-5">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Motorização</label>
    <input name="motorizacao" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-5">
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
<label>Equipamentos</label>
<div class="controls">
  <textarea name="equipamentos" id="texto-principal" class="textarea_editor form-control" rows="15" placeholder="Digitar o texto ..." required data-validation-required-message="Esse texto é obrigatório!"></textarea>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
<label>Descrição</label>
<textarea name="descricao" id="texto-extra2" class="textarea_editor form-control" rows="15" placeholder="Digitar o texto ..."></textarea>
  </div>
  <p>
<label>Galeria de Foto</label>
<BR>
<BR>
<button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Adicionar + Foto</button>
<br>
  <div id="listas">
<div>
  <input name="fotos[]" type="file" class="form-control" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="width: 70%;">
</div>
  </div>
  </p>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Cadastrar</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-inverse">Apagar Tudo</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Olá Leo, muito obrigado por responder.
Eu fiz como mencionou, mas ainda não salva no banco de dados. 
Ficou dessa forma:

foreach($_POST['fotos'] AS $indice => $valor) {
  $values .= " (NULL, '{$id_recuperado}', '{$valor}'),";
}
$values=substr($values, 0, -1);
$sql_fotos = "INSERT INTO `embarcacao_fotos` (`id`, `id_embarcacao`, `arquivo`) VALUES ($values)";

Esta correto?
Abraço e muito obrigado pela sua ajuda meu amigo.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Então Leo, fiz da forma que organizou. No primeiro teste ele deu erro pois tem uma chave fechando de pois de mysqli_close($conn); quando retirei ela o pagina executou. Salvou no BD a embarcação, fez upload do ARQUIVO. Mas não fez upload das FOTOS e nem salvou no banco de dados. O problema ainda esta na parte das FOTOS. Parece que essa parte não esta recebendo FILES do formulário. Leo, agradeço pela força que esta me dando amigo e desculpe a amolação. É que realmente estou empacado ainda nessa etapa do script.

Comment: @AgênciaOzweb, huahuahua, faltou `$Fotos=$_FILES['fotos'];` antes do loop. Me diga, a pasta está sendo criada?

Comment: @AgênciaOzweb Tem certeza que `$pasta = @mkdir("../assets/images/embarcacoes/$id_recuperado");` que esse código está criando a pasta? pra mim não. Veja na minha resposta como funcionou pra mim

Comment: @mkdir("../assets/images/embarcacoes/$id_recuperado"); Esse aqui deu certo, ele cria a pasta no ftp sem problema.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo  $_POST[nome]; funciona ai pra você?  Pior que funcionava normal. Mas com a aspa também funciona.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo - Fiz o teste agora com esse script novo que você editou. DEU CERTOOOO - Assumo que quando abri a minha duvida aqui, eu não esperava ser ajudado. Pois não acreditava que alguém perderia tempo de me ajudar. Mas agradeço a sua ajuda meu amigo. Você foi de extrema importância para mim. Que Deus te abençoe. Muito obrigado de coração meu amigo. Grande abraço.